# Moving the menu bar to top bar ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, gui, gtk, 20.10

Is it possible to move the menu bar up in Ubuntu 20.10 to save useful space on the screen and make the application look much better?

For example:

[image: For Example]

I tried [this solution](https://github.com/gonzaarcr/Fildem), but nothing happens when I run the extension.

Comment: Try right click on the bar, properties.  In props dlg, select Top.  That works on 18.x but I don't know about 20.x

Answer (score 0):

There is a trend, adhered to by the Gnome Shell developers, to move away from traditional pull down menu bars in favor for extensive context menus and a "Hamburger" button. In that context, Gnome Shell developers do not bother implementing a global menu, because it should be gone in the first place.

A Gnome Shell extension, [Gnome Global Application Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) (HUD for Gnome) by sathwik, implemented a global menu. It is not anymore developed, but apparently [another project](https://github.com/gonzaarcr/Fildem) is maintained on Github. It will not necessarily work or work well for all apps. Firefox and Thunderbird, and Gnome apps are listed as a few where it does [not work](https://github.com/gonzaarcr/Fildem/wiki/Using#state-of-the-apps) (yet?).